# How to stop a blind using the RangeController interface or another option

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

Currently, Alexa supports voice commands for opening, closing, and stopping. However, the [RangeController](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-rangecontroller.html) interface provided for blind and curtain control does not implement this functionality.

Any ideas or suggestions on how this can be implemented?

To stop a blind or curtain by Alexa

Answer (score 0):

see here for the author's response: https://github.com/csuermann/node-red-contrib-virtual-smart-home/issues/229

my suggestion (untested) would be to add a powerController interface to the capabilities and some custom semantics so that "stop" essentially turns the blinds "off".  in your receiving logic within node-red, use the power state to cut power to the relays or if you can't do that the other option is to retrieve the current location and issue a move command to that location.

you need to do these manipulations in two places:

1. the custom back-end- you will need to edit endpointTemplates.ts and then re-run serverless deploy.
2. the skill: you will need to edit device-types.js and directives.js and then stop/start node-red.